C++ Builder 12.1P1 | Error Insight showing too many errors
In Tools->Options->Editor->Language, I selected the Error Insight tab with these settings:

and disabled the Visual Assist:

Now, when I create a simple VCL Unit for a form, I get plenty of Error Insight errors:

While the code itself is compiling well, and runs perfectly.
Do I miss some setting to include libraries? Or something else?
I already tried to change settings in the Editor part, but nothing helps. Also in my C++ code, simple declarations of the std namespace classes sometimes provides errors:


Error Insight has been totally buggy since it was first introduced. The first thing I do when installing an update or new version of the IDE is go in and disable it.
